# The R book (Wiley) errata?

Tags: r

Hi I'm learning R using Micheal J. Crawley's book on R 2nd ed.
I have it a snag and I would like to know if the code I'm wrting is at cause or it is a bug that should be reported.

Starting page 36 section 2.6.1 is where I'm having that little problem.

**Here is the command that I have input, the outputs are given as comments:**

```
peas <- c(4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7)
class(peas)
# [1] "numeric"*
length(peas)
# [1] 6*

peas[1:length(peas) %% 2 == 0]
# [1] 7 5 7*
```

Up to here it conformed with the book and the answer make sense in trying to extract the odds number.

Now if one tries to create a new vector "peas1" with the added numbers 4, 2, and 3.
The odds number should be  7 5 7 and 3.

Here the sequence of commands

```
peas1 <- c(4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3)    
length(peas1)
# [1] 9

peas1[1:length(peas1) %% 2 == 0]
#[1] 7 5 7 2
```

**The answer is 7 5 7 and 2 .... Now that is wrong.. 2 is not an odd number!**

Try again adding the number 9 at the end of a copy of the vector "peas1" as "peas2":

```
peas2 <- peas1    
peas2[10] <- 9
peas2
# [1] 4 7 6 5 6 7 4 2 3 9*

peas2[1:length(peas2) %% 2 == 0]
# [1] 7 5 7 2 9*
```

**See the result! 7 5 7 *2* 9**

Now add 2 two more numbers to "peas2"

```
peas2[11] <- 2
peas2[12] <- 8
length(peas2)
# [1] 12

peas2
# [1] 4 7 6 5 6 7 4 2 3 9 2 8

peas2[1:length(peas2) %% 2 == 0]
# [1] 7 5 7 2 9 8
```

We try again and here the even number 2 and 8 appear in the sequence that should give only odd numbers according to the book and its command...

What is wrong the command?[Nothing only the understanding :-)]  or there is a bug? [NO]

**Great Answers you all, I was way out in the left field. THANKS**

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read with newlines in your code examples

Comment: What is wrong with the answers?  The even indices (with R indexing) of `4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3` are 7,5,7, and 2.  I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Ok RishiG, I may come from far away here, bear with me please.  What you refer to as the "even indices" are the elements of the vector that are supposed to be odd, isn't it?   Why "2" which is even appears there? There is much I don't understand...

Comment: The answers are correct. The code does not extract the odd values, it extracts the values at odd indicies of the vector (ie elements 1, 3, 5, etc). If you want to extract the odd elements, you would do `peas2[peas2 %% 2 != 0]`

Comment: The operator `%%` represents modular arithmetic. Basically `n %% 2` is `1` if `n` is odd, and `0` if `n` is even. Therefore, the bit `1:length(peas2) %% 2 == 0` means find all even numbers in the sequence `c(1, 2, 3, ..., length(peas2))` which are even.

Comment: Ok Alex....  Then if I follow MrFlick explanation, the command is looking at the oddness or eveness of the indices and not the values stored at these positions in the vector? And yes MrFlick command works as "advertised"... MrFlick the indices on the vector start at 1 or zero?

Comment: Great now it make sense **Thank you all**. Mr. Crawley could have been a bit more precise and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example might be helpful for you:

```
> myMatrix <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
> myMatrix[1:length(myMatrix) %% 2 == 0]
[1] 2 4 6 8
> myMatrix <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
> myMatrix[1:length(myMatrix) %% 2 == 0]
[1]  3  7 11 15
>
```

So, basically, what you are doing is getting the even *positions* within myMatrix, not the even *values* of my matrix.

Comment: I thought it was the odd values that were requested?

Answer (score 1):

The example code `peas[1:length(peas) %% 2 == 0]` extracts the even **indexed** elements of the peas array, it does not have anything to do with the value of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to extract the odd numbers you can use:

```
odd_peas1 <- split(peas1,peas1%%2)
```

Of which the first element will be a string of the odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between the odd postions and the odd values. If you want the odd values use:

```
 peas2[ peas2 %% 2 != 0 ]
```

If you want the odd positions:

```
peas2[ c(TRUE, FALSE) ]  # argument recycling repeats the sequence along full length.
```

(I don't have a particularly high opinion of Crawley's book, at least in its first version. His explanations of R's syntax and object types in the first edition left a lot to be desired. It caused quite a few questions to Rhelp's mailing list. I didn't see any value in paying the high price for a second copy after the dissappointments caused by its first.)

Comment: Well It seem that I made the mistake then to go for his book... Maybe a book in the R-series at CRC or a book from O'Reilley would be better suited. What would you recommend?

Comment: I looked reasonably carefully at both Matloff's "The Art of R Programming" and de Vries and Meys' "R for Dummies". Both were solid and accurate. As might be expected, Matloff's had more complex stuff about C code at the end, while R for Dummies went into more detail on ggplot2 and RStudio. The value of Crawley would be as a handbook of methods, but I thought his R tutorial was lacking precision in language which I thought was a grave failing. As I said that is only a comment on the first edition. I doubt his publisher is going to send me a review copy.

Comment: Thanks worth looking into these 2 books.  And I agree with your assessment that is tutorial is lacking precision in language, But also in the description of the command he puts down.  It really take an additional effort to understand some of his command, at least in the first chapter... I'll see more later.